# Adding a constant in Multiple Linear Regression using statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels

How can I add a constant to my statsmodels regression.

As of now, the model is like this:

`model = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()`

Comment: add param [hasconst=True](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html)

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation for [`OLS`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html):

> **exog**:     A nobs x k array where nobs is the number of observations and k is the number of regressors. An intercept is not included by default and should be added by the user. See statsmodels.tools.add_constant.

```
X = sm.add_constant(x)
sm.OLS(y,X)
```

Comment: I need to add three variables (age, profession, gender) as constants in the regression. How can I do this?

Comment: @raghavnautiyal Why would age, profession, and gender be constants? I would modify your list of x-values to include those columns from your dataframe (assuming you are working from a dataframe, obviously) or use `statsmodels`' formula syntax.

Comment: I am working with a pandas dataframe. Would adding them to my x values make them constants? Won't that make them be thought of as independent variables then?

Comment: Your question is understood like this "I have a model with 3 independent variables, but there is no constant in it. How can I add it?". The answer is totally acceptable.